# Trying to creates two child processes that print their process ID with counter and a loop to increment the counter

Tags: c, loops

My code currently works but the counter and loop doesn't work yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Driver code

int main()
{
int pid, pid1, pid2;
//int counter = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; ){

        printf("\n");
        printf("parent %d process: counter=%d\n", getpid(), counter);

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            //sleep(1);
            printf("child %d process: counter=%d\n", getpid(), counter);
        counter++;
        }
        else {
            pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0) {
                    printf("child %d process: counter=%d\n", getpid(), counter);
                }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Expected output something like :
parent 1000 process: counter=1

child 1001 process: counter=1

child 10002 process: counter=1

parent 1000 process: counter=2

child 1001 process: counter=2

child 1002 process: counter=2

So im trying to get so it loops with the counter incrementing every time until certain amount of times

when the code it run the output is:
parent 37650 process: counter=1

child 37651 process: counter=1

child 37652 process: counter=1

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Your title suggests fork then loop.  Your code loops and then forks.  Are you required to generate the output in lockstep?  Can you use pipes?

Comment: Your main function is missing a close brace ( `}`  ).  It is unclear where, but likely after the last `if (pid == 0) 
   {
                    printf("child %d process: counter=%d\n", getpid(), counter);
            }  >>>}<<<`

Comment: Note that the two processes do not share any variables after the fork.  Both processes must increment the counter.